# Show Nav Link To Users Signed In

Tags: php, css

Wordpress let's users apply CSS classes to links under Appearances-->Menus.

Well based off of this, I would like to know if there is a way to hide links that have a certain CSS class. So say I apply the CSS class

> .members

to one of my navigation links. The catch is, I would like this link to only show to users that are logged in.

I am a little stuck though as I don't know how to exactly go about doing this. Could something like:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {

}
```

I just don't know how I could target a CSS class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) for this purpose, for example:

```
.members {
    display: none;
}
body.logged-in .members {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: So no need to use PHP at all? Sounds promising.

Comment: as long as your theme is using the `body_class` function, otherwise adding the function is the only php involved.

Comment: I'll check to see if it is. If anything I'll add it. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. Since the PHP will still create the HTML elements, users could just undo the 'display:none' on any 'member-only' functionality.

Comment: well obviously this is not a security measure. where ever those links go should be protected by a logged in check, which one can assume is the case

Comment: There's no need for security because this is more for convenience. The only problem is that I'm trying to apply this to a sub-menu, and it's parent has the display:block property which cancels out the members class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with writing PHP code, you can get an array of each item in the menu by using [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items), and using the object's classes array to figure out which classes are applied to the item. Then you'll use [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) to display the link.

Something along the lines of:

```
    foreach ($items as $item){
        if ( in_array( 'members' , $item->classes ) ) {
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                echo '<a href="'.$menu_item->url.'">link</a>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<a href="'.$menu_item->url.'">link</a>';
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to crack open and fiddle with some PHP, try playing with a permissions plugin such as http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-permissions/ or http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/ . I haven't personally tried to use one to set permissions on a menu, but these plugins will let you control permissions by user role on pretty much everything through the GUI